# SQL: SELECTing a predefined list of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do something like the following statement:

```
SELECT @column_list FROM table_name
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: If you can provide output what you are looking for then this will help community to help you more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic SQL for that:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(500)
DECLARE @column_list varchar(100)
SET @column_list = 'col1, col2, col3'
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @column_list + ' FROM table_name';
EXEC (@sql)
```

Note that `@column_list` could come from the result of another query, e.g. a query on the Information Schema table to find a certain group of columns.

If you need to also build a query dynamically using the columns from the information schema table, then here is one option:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
DECLARE @column_list varchar(500)
SET @column_list = 'col1, col2, col3'

SELECT @column_list = 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + COLUMN_NAME
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = 'yourTable'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @column_list + ' FROM yourTable';
EXEC (@sql)
```

To address the fear of SQL injection, I don't consider the above query to be a big risk, because the column names are coming from SQL Server.

Comment: Little scary on  the injection side this one. :)

Comment: @Larnu I'm assuming someone (e.g. a DBA) would be running this from SSMS, and that the column list would not come from the outside.  But yeah, this totally could be injected.

Comment: In fact, I'm learning ADO.NET and I was trying to avoid SQL injection in my code, any other way?

Comment: That's a scary assumption unto itself Tim.. You *trust* DBA's? ;)

Comment: The second option is certainly a better option if the list is coming from server side and not the user. You could, however, get a failure at run time if the table has a special character in it (i.e. a white space).

Answer (score 1):

This option takes out the danger of injection by ensuring that the column exists within the table, and also quotes the column's name:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Table_name (ID int,
                         SomeString varchar(500));

DECLARE @column_list nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @column_list = 'ID,Somestring'; --Don't use spaces in the list

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) + N'       ' + QUOTENAME(SS.value)
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@column_list,',') SS
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM sys.tables t
                                     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                                     JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                                WHERE t.name = N'Table_name' --Change this the applicable table
                                  AND c.name = SS.value
                                  AND s.name = 'dbo') --change this to the applicable schema
                  FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,9,N'') + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM Table_name;';
PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
DROP TABLE Table_name;
```

If you aren't on SQL Server 2016+ you can make use of [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)/[DelimitedSplit8K_Lead](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/), or am XML splitter (if you are going to pass a list longer than 4000 characters)

Comment: One comment under my answer about SQL injection was more than sufficient.  I don't consider this question to be a big injection risk, because the column names would be coming from within SQL Server, _not_ from the outside, e.g. a UI.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure what you're point is above. The answer here is built the way is it specifically because injection is real. Me not mentioning that that is the way it is built in my answer wouldn't explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you looking for but below query might help you. You can try this.

```
select t.Name AS TableName, c.Name AS ColumnName from sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name  = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```